# Facing issue with border and mso-border-alt property in HTML email template for outlook 2016

Tags: html-table, ms-office, border, html-email, outlook-2016

...  

 ...

Both are giving me only thin line of border. Even I make border as 100px also border width is not increasing in outlook 2016.
What I have to do for this? Is there any solution for this? Can anyone please help me out on this?

Comment: Can you post your code or example code representative of your issue, so we can help you?

Comment: Try _padding with color_ in a td and another color in child table.

Comment: What is giving u thin line?

Answer (score 0):

Word based outlook has a maximum of 8px for borders.